# awk command with search string variable

Tags: awk

`Configuration.xml` has "`mysearchstring`" at position (line) 23.

If I use the following statement, it returns me line 23

```
awk '/"mysearchstring"/{print NR}' Configuration.xml
```

But if I use an assigned variable, it returns me nothing

```
str="mySearchString";awk '/$str/{print NR}' Configuration.xml
```

Can someone tell me what is incorrect in the second statement?

Comment: I am using a bash shell to execute this, so the option given about will not work...

Comment: so the option for command line will not work

Comment: Also if there are 3 lines maching, I would like to get only the first line number.

Comment: Update your question with a proper explanation instead of commenting here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the variable to awk with `-v` and then use the `~` comparison:

```
awk -v myvar="$str" '$0 ~ myvar {print NR}' Configuration.xml
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello
how
are 
you

$ awk '/e/ {print NR}' a <---- hardcoded
1
3

$ awk -v myvar="e" '$0~myvar {print NR}' a <---- through variable
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command-line option `-v` to pass variables to `awk`:

```
awk -v searchstr="$str" '$0 ~ searchstr { print NR }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can pass variable like this, after code:

```
awk '$0~s {print NR}' s="$str" file
```